# How to update claims in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have added claims by using following code

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
                 {
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.BUSINESS_ID, user.BusinessID.ToString()),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.NAME, user.FullName),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.IMAGE, user.ProfileUrl ?? user.LogoUrlEn ?? user.LogoUrlEn ?? ""),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.EMAIL, user.Email),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.USER_ID, user.UserID.ToString()),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.ROLE, user.RoleID.ToString()),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.RIGHTS, string.Join(',', user.RolesRights.Select(S => $"{S.EntityName}|{S.EntityID}|{S.RightID}")))
                };

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true,
            RedirectUri = "/Authentication/Login"
        };

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                              new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                              authProperties);
```

I need to update claim when someone update profile pic I need to update it how can I do that ?

I have tried couple of solution but nothing work .

When someone update profile pic than currently it has to logout and logged in again to see the effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you know the claims is stored inside the cookie when the signin.

So if you want to update the claims, you need to re-call the signin user codes with the updated claims.

Like the previous adding claims codes:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
                 {
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.BUSINESS_ID, user.BusinessID.ToString()),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.NAME, user.FullName),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.IMAGE, user.ProfileUrl ?? user.LogoUrlEn ?? user.LogoUrlEn ?? ""),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.EMAIL, user.Email),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.USER_ID, user.UserID.ToString()),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.ROLE, user.RoleID.ToString()),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.RIGHTS, string.Join(',', user.RolesRights.Select(S => $"{S.EntityName}|{S.EntityID}|{S.RightID}")))
                };

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true,
            RedirectUri = "/Authentication/Login"
        };

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                              new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                              authProperties);
```

Comment: it works !! but just want to confirm that there is no way to update claims ?

Comment: Yes, no way. Claims is stored at client inside the cookie. If you want to update you need update the cookie again.