# How to get the user language Id from database and declare it as global variable, to be called on need, in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Tools used:

- Visual Studio 2022 Community edition
- .NET Core 7.0
- Razor pages

**Explanation**

To lower the number of calls to the database throughout the app, I want to create a global variable for the current user language id, the value of which will be set on users login.

Then this variable will be called on need on every page model, to define the UI language.

I declared a class for the global variable, but could not go further than here.

I can not get the current userId, nor call the database table...

**Question**

How can this be done properly?

**The code**

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    private readonly Models.ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public class Class
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        private int langId = _context.Languages.where(x=>x.UserId = userId).FirstOrDefault().Id;
        public int GetLangId 
        {
            get { return langId; }
            set { langId = value; }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: `_context.Languages.where(x=>x.UserId = userId).FirstOrDefault().Id` might result in a null reference exception if no language was found for that user.

Comment: That's not even valid C#.

Comment: Are you using dependency injection?

Comment: @Good Night Nerd Pride, I have to re emphasise that the class declaration is incomplete, it is not working, it gives errors, that is why i asked here. Yes, i am using dependeny injection. I know that, but it is the smallest of problems.

Comment: You don't want a global-variable. Consider that "global variables" in the traditional sense really don't exist anymore in most modern languages for a good reason. You should learn how to _flow state_ on the stack between call-sites.

Comment: Have a look at ASP.NET's [`IMemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, the best way to achieve your requirement is storing the language id inside the cookie or session.

You could get the language id when the user login in and put it inside the user claims or directly inside the cookie.

Then you could directly use it instead of querying the database every time.

Since this cookie(claims) will expire with the user credential, you doesn't need to consider writing the condition to check the value and query the database again.

It just set one time when the user login and you could read it from the claims or directly from the request cookie based on how you store it.

About how to directly store and use the cookie in razor page, you could refer to below sample:

Store:

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("testid","test");

    }
```

Get:

```
 public void OnGet()
 {
     if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("testid", out string cookieValue))
     {
         // Use your cookieValue
     }
 }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: can you provide some example on how to do this correctly? I found this example but i have not been able yet, to implement it (storing the id inside a cookie or session).   The link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120968/extract-values-from-httpcontext-user-claims#50121176

Comment: Please see my update answer to see how to store the value to the cookie, for claims, it should depend on how you auth your user. About how to update the claims, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74009511/7609093).

Comment: There's no need to store anything - just use the visitor's `Accept-Language:` header.